# How to put multiple figures in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, minipage

[image]I'm trying to insert multiple tikzpictures (scatter plots) in beamer. I've tried follwing the tips given for similar issues, but stil it doesn't even compile.
Here is the original code I used in my article format:

```
\documentclass[mathserif,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Correlations of parents and preschoolers scores}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\begin{axis}[%
 legend style={at={(0.7,0.5)},anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize},
 xlabel=Parents awareness score; pre-assessment,
 ylabel=Child's behavior score; pre-assessment,
 xshift=0.1cm,
 yshift=0.1cm]%
 \addplot [scatter,mark=+,only marks]
    table []{values.data};
 \addplot[draw=none]
    table[
      header=false,
      y={create col/linear regression},
    ] {values.data};
 \addplot[domain=5:30,black]
    {\pgfplotstableregressiona*x + \pgfplotstableregressionb};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\begin{axis}[%
 legend style={at={(0.7,0.5)},anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize},
 xlabel=Parents awareness score; post-assessment,
 ylabel=Child's behavior score; post-assessment,
 xshift=0.1cm,
 yshift=0.1cm]%
 \addplot [scatter,mark=+,only marks]
    table []{values2.data};
 \addplot[draw=none]
    table[
      header=false,
      y={create col/linear regression},
    ] {values2.data};
  \addplot[domain=5:30,black]
    {\pgfplotstableregressiona*x + \pgfplotstableregressionb};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\caption[Correlation between parents awareness score and child's behavior score amid the intervention sample]{Correlation between parents awareness score and child's behavior score amid the intervention sample.}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please fix your example so that it is a complete document that may be run to reproduce the error.

Comment: the code as posted produces `! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'values.data' in 'search path` do you need to plot a data file to show the problem? can you not just plot y=x? Also the question asks about beamer but the example shows article class usage which will not help anyone fix the beamer problem

Comment: About the data file "values.data" I had help reproducing my values to create my scatterplot. Rgarding the document class I used "report" cause that's the original version that is functional. My problem is translating this in beamer, cause I keep getting error messages, that aren't clear.

Comment: the point of the example is to demonstrate the problem you were having! The original `article` code is not very useful nor (probably) are the details of your plots, do you need the tikzpicture at all to show the beamer error or were you getting errors just from `figure`. As you have not said what error you got, nor provided code to reproduce the error how can anyone help you?

Comment: This is the beamer version, my last attempt using columns. the error was "fatal error occured no output file produced". regarding the "values data", I can't figure out how to upload them, if it's possible to replace them with an other exemple so as to facilitate this task , I'm willing to, if you would tell me how.

Comment: `fatal error occured no output file produced".` isn't a tex error that is just your editor saying that _some_ error occurred (which the log file should show) However your posted code does produce a tex error `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].` which gives people something to debug/

Comment: I've compiled with a dummy image instead of your `tikzpictures`. It works. Fix the pictures.

Comment: I've edited the code, using some tips and now it works. thank you all

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]..}
```

that is never going to work, the argument to `\includegraphics` is a *file name* but here you have no images but a tikz picture which is tex code, just delete the `\includegraphics` commands.

---

```
\documentclass[mathserif,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Correlations of parents and preschoolers scores}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[%
 legend style={at={(0.7,0.5)},anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize},
 xlabel=Parents awareness score; pre-assessment,
 ylabel=Child's behavior score; pre-assessment,
 xshift=0.1cm,
 yshift=0.1cm]%
%\addplot [scatter,mark=+,only marks] table []{values.data};
%\addplot[draw=none]
%    table[
%      header=false,
%      y={create col/linear regression},
%    ] {values.data};
%\addplot[domain=5:30,black]
%    {\pgfplotstableregressiona*x + \pgfplotstableregressionb};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[%
legend style={at={(0.7,0.5)},anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize},
xlabel=Parents awareness score; post-assessment,
ylabel=Child's behavior score; post-assessment,
xshift=0.1cm,
yshift=0.1cm]%
%\addplot [scatter,mark=+,only marks]
%table []{values2.data};
%\addplot[draw=none]
%    table[
%      header=false,
%      y={create col/linear regression},
%    ] {values2.data};
%  \addplot[domain=5:30,black]
%    {\pgfplotstableregressiona*x + \pgfplotstableregressionb};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
 \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
 \begin{axis}[%
 legend style={at={(0.7,0.5)},anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize},
 xlabel=Parents awareness score; pre-assessment,
 ylabel=Child's behavior score; pre-assessment,
 xshift=0.1cm,
 yshift=0.1cm]%
% \addplot [scatter,mark=+,only marks]
%     table []{values3.data};
% \addplot[draw=none]
%    table[
%      header=false,
%      y={create col/linear regression},
%    ] {values3.data};
%  \addplot[domain=5:30,black]
%    {\pgfplotstableregressiona*x + \pgfplotstableregressionb};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[%
legend style={at={(0.7,0.5)},anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize},
xlabel=Parents awareness score; post-assessment,
ylabel=Child's behavior score; post-assessment,
xshift=0.1cm,
yshift=0.1cm]%
%\addplot [scatter,mark=+,only marks]
%table []{values4.data};
%\addplot[draw=none]
%    table[
%      header=false,
%      y={create col/linear regression},
%    ] {values4.data};
%  \addplot[domain=5:30,black]
%    {\pgfplotstableregressiona*x + \pgfplotstableregressionb};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage} 
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```